# Multiple items in animation controller when animating player in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, controller, controls, game-physics

I'm trying to animate a Unity3D character with Maximo. I have the mouselook and movement script all done, not I'm up to animating the guy. Whenever I drag and drop the animation .fbx file into the animation controller, a bunch of items stacked on top of each other come up and none of them are a distinguishable animation. I have no idea what to do here. I'm a complete beginner doing this for a school assignment. Thanks in advance for any help!

[Here's the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gmCgQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you add something visually (ss or video link in your animation controller) we can be more helpful.
You should watch this tutorial for more details.
https://learn.unity.com/project/unity-animation-fundamentals

Comment: Hey CptNaed, I just added an ss of the problem. Thank you for assisting.

Comment: 1-) First of all, it is necessary to edit the State positions. To do this, you can hold down on the squares and drag them in the area.

2-) You have to select the animation clips in this State (by clicking on the squares).

3-) Which animation you want to be the default.
You need to link to it with Entry State.
Here the example : https://i.hizliresim.com/177u057.png